# Pass a List of Objects from View to Controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a collection (list) from my view to the controller.

View Url.Action:

```
<div id="graph"><img src="@Url.Action("Draw", "Wishlist", new {list = Model.Products})" alt="Graph" /></div>
```

Controller-Method:

```
public ActionResult Draw(ICollection<Product> list )
        {
            int length = list.Count;
            string[] names = new string[length];
            int[] total = new int[length];
            DateTime week = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
            for (int i=0; i <= lijst.Count; i++)
            {
                list.ForEach(p =>
                {
                    names[i] = p.Name;
                    total[i] = p.NumberPerWeek(week, week.AddDays(7));
                });
            }

            var c = new Chart(width: 250, height: 250)
                .AddSeries(
                    chartType: "bar",
                    yValues: new[] { "10", "20", "30", "40" },
                    xValue: new[] { "50", "60", "78", "80" }
                ).GetBytes("jpg");
            return File(c, "images/bytes");
```

But when I run my project, the list is null.
Suggestions ?

Comment: You don't have any simple way to encode those objects into a querystring.

Comment: Does this compile? You seem to have a typo in your for loop (``lijst.Count``)

Comment: @SLaks is right. But what about giving response with base64 encoded `src` from the start whithout requireing the browser to make additional request for image? Create a helper with your action logic which can do it in place.

Comment: In addition to @ext0's comment you have a termination condition in loop as `i <= lijst.Count`. I suppose that the operator should be `<`.

Comment: You cannot pass a collection using `@Url.Action()`. Internally the method uses `.ToString()` of each property in your model to generate the route/query string values. In your case it would result in `/Wishlist/Draw?list=System.Collections.Generic[Project]`